# core data errors adding new record

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 with Swift. The project is using core data to save Sightings

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
@objc(Sighting)

class Sighting: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var lat: Double
    @NSManaged var lng: Double
    @NSManaged var seen_at: NSDate
}
```

In an IBaction I create a new Sighting

```
@IBAction func addSighting(sender: AnyObject) {
    let coordinate = locationManager.location.coordinate
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let sighting = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Sighting", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as Sighting

    sighting.lat = coordinate.latitude
    sighting.lng = coordinate.longitude
    ...
}
```

On the line "let sighting =" I get the error swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional. Any ideas why?

Replacing the line with

```
    let entityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Sighting", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let sighting = Sighting(entity: entityDescripition!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
```

seems to get past the issue but then it just results in the next line "sighting.lat =" giving the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS > objc_msgSend

coordinate.latitude is correctly returning a CLLocationDegrees

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does marking the class public: `public class Sighting: NSManagedObject` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your Model does not link the entity "Sighting" with the class `Sighting`.  Select the entity in the model editor, and enter the class name in the data model inspector panel on the right:

[image: screenshot]

Note that in Swift, the class name must include the name of your module (app).

Comment: Awesome. I didn't have a class name in the class input. Adding just "Sighting" without the app name seemed to work fine. Thanks!